# Setting state in useEffect and then passing as a prop

Tags: reactjs

Not exactly sure why this isn't working I want to set state based on a passed in prop and then pass the state as a prop, but it doesn't work when I use it in a useEffect. I had originally just used a regular function to do this and it worked, but trying to clean up code and it doesn't seem to work.

```
const Picker = ({choices, activeValue}) => {
  const [clickIndex, setClickIndex] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    choices.forEach((choice, index) => {
      if (activeValue && choice === activeValue) {
        setClickIndex(index);
      }
    });
  }, [choices, activeValue]);

  return (
      <Options
        clickedIndex={clickIndex}
      />
  );
  
}
```

Then in the Options component I set state based on clickedIndex

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ [clickedIndex]: "clicked" });
```

The state always ends up as {null: "clicked"} in the Options component. Even though the props shows to be 2.

Before I had done this, just invoking a function for the Picker component instead of useEffect and it worked.

EDIT: Fixed getInitialClicked implementation

```
const getInitialClicked = () => {
    let clickIndex = null;
    choices.forEach((choice, index) => {
      if (activeValue && choice === activeValue) {
        clickIndex = index;
      }
    }
    return clickIndex;
}

  return (
      <Options
        clickedIndex={getInitialClicked()}
      />
  );
```

What am I not understanding with this? Is is bad form to do it the function way or does it not actually matter?

Answer (score 0):

The value passed to `useState` only gets checked by React when the component mounts. On further re-renders, the value is ignored, and instead React uses the value that component has in state (passed into it on mount).

A good way to deal with this sort of thing is to not duplicate state between components, because keeping them in sync is a pain and can lead to confusing code. In the Options, remove

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ [clickedIndex]: "clicked" });
```

and instead just reference the `clickedIndex` prop. If you also need an object for rendering or something, construct the object in the main block of the Options function:

```
const clickedIndexObject = { [clickedIndex]: 'clicked' };
```

Comment: Oops your right. I fixed it to how I implemented it so that it does return something.

Comment: The two implementations look like they'll have the same behavior wrt what's passed down: it'll first pass down `null`, and then later, it'll pass down something else of the click index changes. Maybe in your function approach, your Options component was different, and using the prop only instead of putting it into state too?

Comment: The non-useEffect does work correctly and looking into it, I think that is an OK way to do it after all. I just learned about useEffect and just thought that's the better way but maybe not since I don't even need the state in the Picker component and can just reference the prop. I'm kind of unsure of when to actually use useEffect.

Comment: The issue to keep in mind with `useEffect` is that it updates the state asynchronously. If you change one state, and have an effect hook that detects that change and changes a different state, child components will first see the first change in a re-render, and *then* the second change after another re-render. When I have multiple related state updates to make like that, I avoid `useEffect` and instead call both state setters immediately (like in a click handler).